# How to install sonatype nexus in Linux through YAML Scripting?

Tags: linux, installation, sonatype

I am New YAML to Language and for Sonatype Nexus also.So pls anyone refer me how to install sonatype nexus in Linux through YAML script with procedures if possible and pls share any external Links also.It would be Helpful.

Welcoming your appreciate.

Thanks and Regards
Nandha Kumar
Lead Administrator,IBM
Bangalore,India

Answer (score 0):

Installing Nexus on Linux

1. [Download](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/go) Nexus from Sonatype
2. Follow [Instructions](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/_installing_nexus.html) to unzip and place it in right directories on server
3. [Start](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/install-sect-running.html) Nexus using the bundled Jetty application server
4. [Instructions](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/install-sect-as-a-war.html) to install as a war file on other app servers/servlet containers.

YAML has a bunch of [bindings](http://yaml.org/) including Python, Perl that you could use to write a script for this.

Comment: The 'instructions' link is not working anymore. [This](https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/installing.html) is the new one. But the Sonartype website is not very documented.